# angular 2 passing service method as parameter in component?

Tags: angular, typescript

In component:

```
myFunction(): void {
    this.myOtherFunctoin(this._myService.serviceMethod);
}

private myOtherFunction(func : Function){ 
    func();
}
```

In service calls

```
serviceMethod(){
   this.somethingMethod();  // "this" is coming as undefined in debugger
   this.somethingVariable = true;
}
```

**I wanted to pass method as a parameter like delegate in c#
 Am I doing something wrong here**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `bind(this)` or anonymous arrow wrapper:

```
this.myOtherFunction(this._myService.serviceMethod.bind(this))
```

Comment: I actually tired this but for some reason was not working for me , getting the reference of "this" wrong. For me it works like this : ** let tempVariable = this._myService.serviceMethod ; this.myOtherFunction(this._myService.serviceMethod.bind(tempVariable)); **

Comment: Use: `this.myOtherFunction(this._myService.serviceMethod.bind(this._myService))`